# Extensão do chrome rodar apenas em subdiretório

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extensão

Estou fazendo uma extensão do chrome que faz algumas mudanças no HTML do instagram, então no `manifest.json` coloquei assim:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["*://*.instagram.com/*"],
    "run_at": "document_idle",
    "all_frames": true,
    "js": ["contentScript.js"]
  }
],
```

Então o meu `contentScript.js` só roda na página do instagram. Mas eu queria agora fazer umas alterações apenas na página de stories, ou seja `instagram.com/stories/xxxxxx`.

Como faço para uma função ou arquivo só rodar em determinado subdiretório do site, enquanto outra roda no site inteiro?

O que rola é que eu tenho uma parte do código que é usada na base, e outra só nos stories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separe em 2 scripts um só para o site todo e outro especifico para o stories, algo como:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["*://*.instagram.com/*"],
    "run_at": "document_idle",
    "all_frames": true,
    "js": ["contentScript.js"]
  }, {
    "matches": ["*://*.instagram.com/stories/*"],
    "run_at": "document_idle",
    "all_frames": true,
    "js": ["storiesScript.js"]
  }
],
```

Sendo `contentScript.js` para todas páginas `*://*.instagram.com/*` e sendo `storiesScript.js` para todas páginas `*://*.instagram.com/stories*`

---

Alternativamente você pode usar o evento `popstate` dentro de `contentScript.js` para detectar mudanças de endereço com `pushState` e `replaceState` que é comum em no `instagram.com`, nesse caso **não** irá separar os scripts, então faça algo como dentro de `contentScript.js`:

```
//Isolado escopo
(function (w, h) {
    var pushState = h.pushState,
        replaceState = h.replaceState;

    h.pushState = function (state, title, url) {
        setTimeout(detectChange, 1);

        return pushState.call(h, null, title, url);
    };

    h.replaceState = function (state, title, url) {
        setTimeout(detectChange, 1);

        return replaceState.call(h, null, title, url);
    };

    // dispara quando o script é inserido na página
    detectChange();

    // adiciona o evento popstate para quando o usuário usar back ou foward
    w.addEventListener('popstate', detectChange);

    function detectChange() {
        console.log('troca de URL');

        if (location.pathname.indexOf("/stories/") === 0) {
            // Execute algo nas páginas de stories, exemplo:
            funcoesStories();
        } else {
            // Execute algo nas outras páginas, exemplo:
            outrasFuncoes();
        }
    }
})(window, history);
```

E no manifest.json deve usar somente:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["*://*.instagram.com/*"],
    "run_at": "document_idle",
    "all_frames": true,
    "js": ["contentScript.js"]
  }
],
```

Usei `location.pathname` para pegar o PATH da URL e com `.indexOf("/stories/") === 0` checa se o PATH é /stories/ ou outra página dentro dela.

Note que reescrevi o `history.pushState` e `history.replaceState` pois eles não disparam o evento `popstate` (detalhes em https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate)

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado! Eu sabia que era algo simples, mas não fazia ideia de como fazer. Ajudou muito

Comment: Guilherme, o arquivo parece não carregar se eu abro os stories, apenas se eu copio o link e crio uma nova página (Acredito que seja algo relacionado à página não recarregar, e sim só o url mudar). Alguma ideia do que posso fazer em relação a isso?

Comment: @VitorCeolin atualizei a resposta;

Comment: @VitorCeolin atualizei o código, tinha esquecido que pushState e replaceState não disparam o popstate, então dessa forma provavelmente vai resolver para todas situações de navegação.